# View a precise revision of a build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps :

We have a build pipeline, configured through the GUI editor.

I would like to share a link with my colleagues which points to a precise revision of this build pipeline
("sharing with my colleagues" = mention it in our internal issue tracker)

**Question**

- Is there a way (through devop's GUI) to view the state of a build pipeline at a given revision?
- A way with a shareable url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can show a precise revision of a build definition in the UI without to revert to this revision. you can see a revision of the build in a JSON format. if you go to "History" Tab and compare the difference between versions:

[image]

You will get a screen with the current version and the other (in JSON).

The URL in the comparison page is also unique to this comparison so you can share it.

Another option is to use the Rest API to get the precise revision, but also only in JSON format:

```
https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/{project-GUID}/_apis/build/Definitions/{build-id}?revision={revision-id}
```

The above call returns a JSON of specific revision, you can also share it.

(You can get all the revisions with [Get Definition Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get%20definition%20revisions?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API).